# Standard notation for the category of contravariant functors to Set

Tags: category-theory, notation, math-history

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. Which notation is standard for the category of contravariant functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$: $$\mathcal{C}^{\vee}\ \mathrm{or}\  \mathcal{C}^{\wedge}?$$ 
I have seen both notations used by the *same* authors in different places!

Comment: I seem to recall that there's also $\widehat{\mathcal{C}}$ that exists as a notation. If I remember correctly, McLane attributes this one to the french school

Comment: You should get over the idea of "standard" notation.

Comment: @DerekElkins Ok, but I want to know which notation I should use. Are you saying I should just choose whichever notation that I desire?

Comment: @Must To some extent, as long as you define it, *yes*! You should try to avoid unnecessarily creating new notation. It's also nice to gear your notation to the intended audience, and often that means adopting whatever notation is most common, but you usually need to judge that based on your own experience. There is still a large amount of latitude for your own preferences.

Comment: To actually answer your question, in my experience $\widehat{\mathcal C}$ is the most common out of the notations you've used, but you definitely can't expect it to be understood without comment. It's also very common to not have a special notation and use whatever notation is used for functor categories, e.g. $[\mathcal C^{op},\mathbf{Set}]$ or $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal C^{op}}$. I've also seen $\mathrm{Psh}(\mathcal C)$ which makes sense in a context where you'll talk about sheaves and use notation like $\mathrm{Sh}(\mathcal C)$. I'm sure there are other variations.

Comment: @DerekElkins Ok, thank you!